# Shell script isn't run by ant using exec tag if script is in a different directory

Tags: java, android, ant

Here is the portion of my ant script that doesn't work properly.

```
<exec executable="/bin/bash">
    <arg value="../libraries/android-mapviewballoons/android-mapviewballoons/mapimports.sh" />
    <arg value="a"/>
</exec>
<exec executable="/bin/bash">
    <arg value="mapimports.sh"/>
    <arg value="a"/>
</exec>
```

The first script never runs, but the second script runs fine.  No errors are returned.  I've tried running both scripts manually and they work.

Does anyone know how I might debug this or make it work?

Comment: may be the path obtained from ../libraries/ is not correct. You can try printing current working directory using "pwd", it will give you a clue

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that wasn't the problem.  That is the correct path.

Comment: @MattWear don't use relative paths, I know you state that it isn't the issue, but changing directory will trigger this symptom.

Answer (score 0):

I got something similar running with:

```
<exec executable="bash" dir="./pathToScript/" >
    <arg value="script.sh" />
    <arg value="param" />
</exec>
```